# mailto div content outlook

Tags: javascript, outlook, mailto

```
$("#mail").click(function() {
location.href = "mailto:?subject=test&body="+$("#mailbody").html();
});
```

I am trying to add mail body the contents (5 tables) of #mailbody div. But Outlook gets it as text. Like `<table><tr>..`

Is it about Outlook settings or can't i make this with javascript?

Comment: You can't inject HTML into a `mailto:` link.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Here is RFC that defines mailto URL scheme:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368

Take a look at it wrt encoding special characters.